# Is the order notification email avaiable by default in Magento 1.9.1 version?

Tags: php, orders, ce-1.9.1.0, xml, order-email

but in magento 1.9.1 the order notification email are available by default ?, because It does not work

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure whether I understand the question.

You mean in 1.9.1 is no order confirmation mail send after ordering?

Sure, there is a order confirmation mail send after the order took place. Are you sure you have an SMTP server installed? Check the logs and read [Fundamentals for debugging a Magento store](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/428/fundamentals-for-debugging-a-magento-store)

Comment: yes, because is some forum read  not have by default send message order ,probable in old version

Answer (score 0):

Yes notification email are available by default but you may have do do some setup.

Do you have your cron running ? On the new magento version mails are send with the cron.

To set the cron with shell access (for linux ) you can do :

```
crontab -e
```

Then add one of these (the cron will run every 5 minutes :

```
*/5 * * * * /bin/sh /[magento_path]/cron.sh */5 * * * * /bin/bash /[magento_path]/cron.sh 

*/5 * * * * /usr/bin/php /[magento_path]/cron.php */5 * * * * /usr/local/bin/php -f /[magento_path]/cron.php
```

More info [here](http://help.sweettoothrewards.com/article/395-setting-up-cron-jobs-in-magento).

Hope this help you.